# literal number as data constructor in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell recently. And I keep wondering if I can use literal number as data constructor, like Integer,Int, Word do.
For example, for the following code,

```
data MyBool = Zero | One
         deriving(Bounded, Eq, Show, Enum)
toBool Zero = False
toBool One = True
fromBool False = Zero
fromBool True = One
myAnd = ff (&&) toBool fromBool
myOr = ff (||) toBool fromBool

ff pp fp pf x y= pf $ pp (fp x) (fp y)
```

what I want to do is replace Zero with 0, One with 1, so that I can use something like : `myAnd (1::MyBool) (0::MyBool)`.
I did look into the source code of ghc, I find something like:

```
data Int = GHC.Types.I# GHC.Prim.Int#
data Word = GHC.Types.W# GHC.Prim.Word#
```

And as I researched `Int#` is 'unbox type', which must be the key that enabled them to use literal number as data constructor.
So how could I make my type use literal number as data constructor like Int and Word do?
(Don't hesitate to ask if the question's ambiguous.)

Comment: Here's a really twisted/ingenious example of using numeric literals as data constructors: http://augustss.blogspot.com/2009/02/more-basic-not-that-anybody-should-care.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a `Num` instance for your `MyBool` type and define:

```
fromInteger 0 = Zero
fromInteger 1 = One
```

or perhaps:

```
fromInteger n = if even n then Zero else One
```

so that it isn't partial.

And in that case you can write `myAnd 0 1` - you won't need the `::MyBool` type annotations.

The instance definition can be as short as:

```
instance Num MyBool where
    fromInteger n = if even n then Zero else One
```

You'll get warnings about missing implementations, but if you don't use those operations on your `MyBool` values you'll be okay. If you want a complete Num instance I would probably go this route:

```
instance Enum MyBool where
  fromEnum Zero = 0
  fromEnum One  = 1
  toEnum n      = if even n then Zero else One

instance Num MyBool where
  fromInteger   = toEnum . fromInteger
  a + b         = toEnum (fromEnum a + fromEnum b)
  a * b         = toEnum (fromEnum a * fromEnum b)
  negate a      = a
  abs a         = a
  signum        = toEnum . signum . fromEnum
```

**Update**

I see that you already have derived `Enum` and `Eq`, but you probably will want to use the Enum instance I gave since it handles integer values outside of the range [0..1] and it's useful in defining the Num instance.

Comment: Don't forget the `Eq` instance for number-style pattern matching.

Comment: I just noticed the OP already has specified `deriving (Bounded, Eq, Show, Enum)` but I added a comment about perhaps using my Enum definition

Comment: Fantastic! Works like a charm!

Comment: Oh, I finally understand, according to this page [link](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#rebindable-syntax), the literal "1" means "Prelude.fromInteger 1". So every time I use "1",  `Prelude.fromInteger 1` is called, which gives whatever type belongs to Num.